# Make changes, save but cordova run a previous code

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I’ve a very strange problem from some days…
I’m working on a Ionic 3 Angular 5 app
I make some changes on code, save it and run:
npm i
ionic cordova run browser -lc

Looking log on terminal i see that it’s running a previous code
I’ve tried to delete npm cache, close terminal or vs.code but nothing

Someone has same problem ?
Some help ?

Comment: Do you have the same issue with “ionic serve”? I think the command you run is no longer the one you should use.

Comment: Do you use caching? In similar issues i saw that people did complete reinstalls for ionic and cordova but never saw a real root cause.

Comment: same problems using "ionic serve".. it's making me crazy.. also because some days it works fine..

Comment: i've installed ionic and cordova in standard way.. how can i check if there's some kind of cache ? i've just use "npm cache clear --force" but not solve..

Comment: I reboot my mac and all it's ok now..

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, but try deleting the folder `www`  or use `ionic serve`.